# Reading from client stream in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm follow this tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using
write my own code [I'm not show it here, because it's too long]

anyway, I have tested it with telnet in windows, and the problem is 
everytime I try to send request to server from telnet,
the server read all client buffer even when I use backslash to delete character
so the output in server like this "TESD\b\b\bT"
I just want the server read the String without \b.
it's because telnet send all the character including \b or just my
StreamReader fault in my server, I don't know.

Comment: Are you actually implementing the telnet protocol anywhere in your server?

Comment: no,the server just receive and send string to server.
I'm not implementing any telnet protocol, I just use telnet.exe in windows to test the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the [Telnet Linemode Option](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/35.htm), which the Windows `telnet` seems to not properly support. I recommend using `PuTTY` with *Connection type: Raw* - there you can check and change *Local line editing* under *Change Settings… / Terminal / Line discipline options* (*Auto* should do).